# yfinance not returning full chart

Tags: python

I am trying to understand yfinance so I can automate some stock information and whatnot. The issue is that when I receive the chart from the ticker function, some of the columns are replaced with '...' I have no idea why it is doing this and any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import yfinance as yf

aapl= yf.Ticker("aapl")
aapl_historical = aapl.history(period="10d")

text_file = open(r'C:\Users\(My name)\source\repos\Stock Futures\Stock Futures\Stock Data.txt', 'a+')
aapl_historical = str(aapl_historical)
text_file.write(aapl_historical)
text_file.write('\n\n\n')
text_file.close()
```

Here is the output:

```
Date                                ...                         
2021-03-18  122.879997  123.180000  ...          0             0
2021-03-19  119.900002  121.430000  ...          0             0
2021-03-22  120.330002  123.870003  ...          0             0
2021-03-23  123.330002  124.239998  ...          0             0
2021-03-24  122.820000  122.900002  ...          0             0
2021-03-25  119.540001  121.660004  ...          0             0
2021-03-26  120.349998  121.480003  ...          0             0
2021-03-29  121.650002  122.580002  ...          0             0
2021-03-30  120.110001  120.400002  ...          0             0
2021-03-31  121.650002  123.519997  ...          0             0

[10 rows x 7 columns]
```

As you can see, Some of the columns are not displaying properly. Thanks again for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who stumble upon this and need help.

adding

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

to the beginning of the code solved my issue.